# Select an object from a collection in anylogic?

Tags: collections, gis, anylogic

I need to simulate an earthquake on my GIS map. I've created some regions on my GIS map and I've created a collection in which put these regions. Now, I need to create a function which choose one of these regions (which may a probability for each one) and in this choosen region model have to locate eartquake epicenter (I created an agent called earthquake).

1- How can I type this code in my body function?

2- Which type of collection do I need to choose (e.g. "Linked List", "Tree map". etc.) ?

3- How can I create after this, earthquake latitude and longitude (I need to send Tir agent on epicenter) ?
I upload below pics to make understandable.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFMQ2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBRqr.png)

Comment: Hey Alfonso, welcome to SOF and AnyLogic. Please always only ask 1 specific question per issue. SOF works like a knowledge base. See here for some intro advise for AnyLogic SOF users: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: All three questions are linked with my issue. Anyway, I haven't found something on this site. Do you know how can i fix my issue? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome Alphonso. How are you initiating the earthquake?

Comment: @NickA, thanks. I thought to select first one of these regions and then choose one of these thanks to a probability which each one have. I'm thinking to use a list object in which put these regions object and recall one of these regions from the list with an event. But I don't know if it's correct. How can I do? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Spontaneous idea:
I would work with an array list, each line is a region as a string.
Then use another variable to find out which region you need (e.g. use a normal distribution, if the value is above a threshold it is region B, otherwise it is A).
As region A and B are in different lines of the collection, your `i` for the following code changes: `collection.get(i);`.